# Cannot Ping External IP from Xamarin Android Release Build

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using InetAddress to ping an external IP address from a Xamarin.Android app. It works in DEBUG mode but fails in RELEASE mode.

```csharp
private bool Ping(string ip)
{
     InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.GetByName(ip);
     return inetAddress.IsReachable(1000); // 1 second timeout
}
```

If you are utilizing the same IP, will return `true` in DEBUG mode but `false` in RELEASE mode.

**project file config**

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{6A6B026F-9CFE-4692-8D72-C41E577C0718}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>XamarinDemo</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>XamarinDemo</AssemblyName>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
        <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
        <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
        <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
        <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
        <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v10.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
        <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
        <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
        <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
        <Optimize>False</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>True</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
        <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
        <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
        <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;arm64-v8a;x86_64</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>True</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
        <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
        <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
        <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Is the release mode configuration wrong or missing any permissions? Or is there any other way to ping ip in release mode for xamarin android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value of **Optimize** from `true` to `false` may resolve the issue. I believe that this setting is causing the code in the `InetAddress` class to function incorrectly.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
        <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
        <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
        <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Glad to see that you've solved it. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.